# Modulus in a for loop for creating a rectangle

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, bit-manipulation, modulus

This is an incredibly specific question, as i simply need to know if this pattern has a name and if there is a more effective way of doing it. (disregard the obvious declaration in the for loop)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    int mod = i % 2;
    int mod2 = ((i % 4) / 2).ceil() & (mod * 15);

}
```

now this outputs a cool "01020102" pattern that i need for construction of a rectangle... but I don't like its clumsiness

now this code can access an array in a pattern that allows one to create a box with 4 corners and 4 sides (as it accesses [corner length, evenside length, oddside length])

if anyone has a better pattern for this, that would be great if not... I guess this is fine

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Are you trying to make a function which produces the order with which 2 divides n? That pattern starting with n=1 is 0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,... https://oeis.org/A007814 Btw, your for loop doesn't output anything and in the languages I know you are applying a useless ceiling on an integer argument.

Comment: this happens to be Dart (programming language by google)... but its really a math question that I'm asking... this math happens to produce what i need. if you were to take out the ceil... it doesn't output quite right... and what i need specifically is the 0,1,0,2 ... with the mod it simply repeats. I have explained that it very elegantly allows me to access data for rectangle construction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I do not see any point in your code ...

- but there are many ways how to create repetitive series you need
- here few examples

example1:

```
int tab[4]={0,1,0,2};
for (int i=0;i<8;i=(i+1)&3) output(tab[i]);
```

- use a table

example2:

```
for (int i=0;i<8;i+=4) 
 {
 output(0);
 output(1);
 output(0);
 output(2);
 }
```

- direct output

Comment: I wanted to avoid allocating, or inlining, (the use of modulus, and the very strange hack i have now are decently fast... the only thing i can think of that would be faster is an if statement to produce the 0s)... the second one doesn't make a whole lot of sense for my particular case (this isn't a school project or example code to see what pops up in the console)

Comment: @MasterLetch you did not specify the output ...  this is what your OP text implies for me. If you want speed then `Ceil` is surely not as fast as any of these due to floating conversions not to mention the modulus ...,, static allocation of 4 values is nothing complicated ....

Comment: the ceil might be gross, but a modulus in a computer is a truncation... making it broken fast... but I think i get what you are saying, a 4 byte array is absolutely nothing to allocate (because of course... its simply an int)